# Can't locate the file using Spring-MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring-MVC framework. Please see my code below.

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.acnovate;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
    <web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**HelloWeb-servlet.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.acnovate" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now after start my tomcat server I am trying to open "http://localhost:8080/HelloWeb/hello" link. but it is always giving me error

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
```

I also checked my all folders. I followed the process step by step. I tried so many times and also checked my all files, but didn't get any solution or hints to remove this problem.

Can anyone suggest me how to get out from this error.

Comment: your dispatcher-servlet looks exactly like your web.xml. did you paste te wrong thing?

Comment: @JackFlamp hey thanks ,I updated my questions. Please have a look again.

Comment: you have given the base-package as  "com.tutorialspoint" whereas  HelloController is present in the "com.acnovate" package. Spring won't be able to scan this class

Comment: @amdg hey i also tried this but didn't get the actual output.

Comment: do you have your hello.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp folder? and not directly under WEB-INF?

Comment: @JackFlamp Yes I have hello.jsp in WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very annoyed so I started testing all your config. This way I managed to access the controller method and get the response:

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.acnovate" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I think the reason was that you were not calling the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the `HelloWeb-servlet.xml`

Comment: Please recheck my answer, I've just tested starting with your plain config until I managed to get the answer from the server and I rewrote my answer based in the results of my test

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts, but on my machine it is still not running. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet XML you are scanning the 'com.tutorialspoint' package instead of the 'com.acnovate' package that contains your controller.

Comment: How are you configuring your app context to 'HelloWeb'?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the @RequestMapping on the method to `@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

..or remove the `@Requestmapping` from the class and set `value="/hello"` on the method instead.